# How to customize submit forms in Dspace?

Tags: dspace

I use XMLUI in DSpace 5.5, it is possible to customize the HTML submission form? Has any file in dspace to allow this?

Answer (score 3):

The input form customizations are set in https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/input-forms.xml

See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Submission+User+Interface for documentation of the process.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want to add a Gender drop-down with options: "N/A", "Male" and "Female" to the first page (step) of the submission form, you need to add a proper field to a Metadata Schema and modify UI accordingly. Do these steps in the XML UI. Sign in as an administrator. In the context menu, under **ADMINISTRATIVE**, **Registries**, go to **Metadata**. It is highly recommended to use **local** metadata schema when you want to add a metadata field to DSpace. Each metadata field (including built-in or custom) comprises 3 parts: *schema*, *element*, and *qualifier*. For example in field *`dc.contributor.author`*, *`dc`* is schema, *`contributor`* is element, and *`author`* is qualifier. In our example the field can be defined as *`local.contributor.gender`*, so *`local`* is schema, *`contributor`* is element, and *`gender`* is qualifier. In **Metadata registry** page, click on *`local`* so you see the fields defined in *`local`* schema and the following inputs to add new fields to the schema:

[image]

As you see, there is no need to type the schema part i.e. *`local`* and just type *`contributor`* and *`gender`* in the specified inputs. You can also add a note in **Scope Note**. Click on **Add new metadata field** to save the field.

Now the UI time! Edit file `[dspace-source]/dspace/config/input-forms.xml` as follows. Look at this part of the file:

```
<form-definitions>
   <form name="traditional">
     <page number="1">
         <field ...>
         <field ...>
         ...
     </page>
   </form>
<form-definitions>
```

Add the following `<field>` element along with the other `<field>` elements:

```
   <field>
     <dc-schema>local</dc-schema>
     <dc-element>contributor</dc-element>
     <dc-qualifier>gender</dc-qualifier>
     <repeatable>false</repeatable>
     <label>Gender</label>
     <input-type value-pairs-name="common_gender_contributor">dropdown</input-type>
     <hint>Select the gender of the author.</hint>
     <required></required>
   </field>
```

This [document](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-AddingValue-Pairs), explains each of the above sub-elements:

> - dc-schema (Required) : Name of metadata schema employed.
> - dc-element (Required) : Name of the Dublin Core element entered in this field,  e.g. contributor.
> - dc-qualifier: Qualifier of the Dublin Core element entered in this
>     field, e.g. when the field is contributor.advisor the value of this
>     element would be advisor. Leaving this out means the input is for an
>     unqualified DC element.
> - repeatable: Value is true when multiple values
>     of this field are allowed, false otherwise.
> - label (Required): Text to display as the label of this field, describing
>     what to enter, e.g. "Your Advisor's Name".
> - input-type(Required): Defines the kind of interactive widget to put in the form to collect the Dublin Core value. Content must be one of the following keywords:
>
>   - onebox – A single text-entry box.
>   - dropdown – Choose value(s) from a "drop-down" menu list. Note: You must also include a
>       value for the value-pairs-name attribute to specify a list of menu
>       entries from which to choose.
>   - ...
> - hint (Required): Content is the text that will appear as a
>     "hint", or instructions, next to the input fields.
> - required: When this element is included with
>     any content, it marks the field as a required input.

Since the widget is a drop-down, the element `<input-type>` has been defined like this:

```
<input-type value-pairs-name="common_gender_contributor">dropdown</input-type>
```

`common_gender_contributor` is the name of a `<value-pairs>` element that is  defined as follows:

```
<value-pairs value-pairs-name="common_gender_contributor"
             dc-term="">
    <pair>
        <displayed-value>N/A</displayed-value>
        <stored-value/>
    </pair>   
    <pair>
        <displayed-value>Male</displayed-value>
        <stored-value>male</stored-value>
    </pair>
    <pair>
        <displayed-value>Female</displayed-value>
        <stored-value>female</stored-value>
    </pair>     
</value-pairs>
```

The `<value-pairs>` element is placed under `<form-value-pairs>` element, along with the other `<value-pairs>` elements in file `[dspace-source]/dspace/config/input-forms.xml`. Rebuild DSpace and you see the new drop-down in the submission page.